Getting undefined trying to append value to display
i am following along a video on making a calculator after making my own to see how it can be done much better and in the video it seems to work for him but i am getting only undefined and the code is a 100% match.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <input id="display" readonly>
            <div id="keys">
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()" class="operatorBtn">+</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">7</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">8</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">9</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()"class="operatorBtn">-</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">4</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">5</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">6</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()"class="operatorBtn">*</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">1</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">2</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">3</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()"class="operatorBtn">/</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">0</button>
                <button onclick="appendToDisplay()">.</button>
                <button onclick="calculate()">=</button>
                <button onclick="clearDisplay()"class="operatorBtn">AC</button>

            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="java.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>

const display = document.getElementById("display")

function appendToDisplay(input){
    display.value += input;
}

function clearDisplay(){

}

function calculate(){

}

please help me understand this thank you in advance

You're not passing any argument to appendToDisplay.

Your appendToDisplay() function expects a parameter to be passed. When you call it from your "click" handlers, however, you pass nothing.

Solution
Each <button> has text that can be accessed with .textContent which is what needs to be appended to the display.value. Pass the event object and use event.target to determine which <button> the user clicked.
<button onclick="appendToDisplay(event)">3</button>

function appendToDisplay(event) {
  display.value += event.target.textContent; // 3
}

⭐ Better Solution
Don't use on-event attributes they suck:
<button onclick="functionName()"> <!--  --> 

Use .addEventListener() method and delegate events as well:
form.addEventListener("click", clickHandler); // 

function clickHandler(event) {
  if (event.target.id === "btnA") {
    // Do something...
  } else if (event.target.id === "btnB") {
    // do something else...
  } else {
    // otherwise terminate this function
    return;
  }
}

In the example below, everything is wrapped in a <form> so forms and HTMLFormControlsCollection properties can be used. Certain <button>s are en/disabled under certain conditions in order to ensure that each number has no more than one decimal and that there is never any operators adjacent to each other. Details are commented in example.


// Reference <form id="calc">
const calc = document.forms.calc;
/*
  Reference all form controls in form#calc.
  In this layout it is all:
    - <fieldset>
    - <output>
    - <button>
*/
const io = calc.elements;
// Reference <output id="lcd">
const lcd = io.lcd;
// Gather all four button[name=opr] into an array.
const operators = Array.from(io.opr);
/* NOTE:
  Any mention of [num], [opr], or [dec] are actually
  button[name=num], button[name=opr], or button[name=dec] 
  respectively which depending on the context can be singular 
  or plural.
*/
/**
 * This event handler determines whether the user clicked 
 * [num], [opr], or [dec] and will append the <button>'s text 
 * to output#lcd.value.
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 */
function showKey(event) {
  // The element the user clicked
  const clk = event.target;
  // If the user clicked a [num]...
  if (clk.name === "num") {
    // append it's text to output#lcd.value...
    lcd.value += clk.textContent;
    // and enable all [opr]...
    operators.forEach(opr => opr.disabled = false);
    // otherwise if user clicked a [opr]...
  } else if (clk.name === "opr") {
    // append it's text to output#lcd.value...
    lcd.value += clk.textContent;
    // disable all [opr]...
    operators.forEach(opr => opr.disabled = true);
    // and enable [dec]...
    io.dec.disabled = false;
    // otherwise if user clicked [dec]...
  } else if (clk.name === "dec") {
    // append it's text to output#lcd.value...
    lcd.value += clk.textContent;
    // disable all [opr]...
    operators.forEach(opr => opr.disabled = true);
    // and enable [dec]
    clk.disabled = true;
    /*
      otherwise if user clicked neither [num], [opr[, or [dec]
      terminate this function.
    */
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function calcExp(event) {} //

function zeroLCD(event) {} //

/*
  Register form#calc to the "click", "reset", and "submit" 
  events. 
  "click" events are delegated to <button type="button">
  "reset" events are delegated to <button type="reset">
  "submit" events are delegated to <button>
*/
calc.addEventListener("click", showKey);
calc.addEventListener("reset", zeroLCD); //
calc.addEventListener("submit", calcExp); //
// Not part of the question.
:root {
  font: 3vmax/1.2 Consolas
}

#header {
  height: 1rem;
  width: min-content
}

#lcd {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: right;
}

#keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: min-content
}

button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<form id="calc">
  <fieldset id="header">
    <output id="lcd"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="keys">
    <button type="reset">AC</button>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <button name="opr" type="button">/</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">7</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">8</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">9</button>
    <button name="opr" type="button">*</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">4</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">5</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">6</button>
    <button name="opr" type="button">-</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">1</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">2</button>
    <button name="num" type="button">3</button>
    <button name="opr" type="button">+</button>
    <div></div>
    <button name="num" type="button">0</button>
    <button name="dec" type="button">.</button>
    <button>=</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>




Check if the function is global through the console (typeof appendToDisplay).
If it returns undefined, then it isn't. However, you can do this manually by attaching it to window like so:
window.appendToDisplay = function(input) {
    const display = document.getElementById('display');
    display.value += input;
}

Hope this also helps!
